# How to inherit using declarations from base class

Tags: c++, templates, using, crtp

I declare types within class `Config`, pass this to base class `Parent` so `Child` can access.

The idea is each `Child` (there are many) won't have to keep declaring it's own `using` declarations, because they are already in `Parent`.

However, this doesn't compile. `Child` cannot see `Parent::Type`.

Is it possible to achieve this somehow?

```
template<class CONFIG>
struct Parent
{
    using Type = typename CONFIG::Type;
    // Plus a lot more types....
};

template<class CONFIG>
struct Child : public Parent<CONFIG>
{
    void x(Type p){}     // Compiler error. Cannot see Parent::Type
};

struct Config
{
    using Type = int; 
    // Plus a lot more types....
};

int main() 
{
    Child<Config> c;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are automatically inherited, but not visible. The reason these are not visible is, template base class is not considered during name lookup. It's not specific to types, same occurs with member variables. If you want them to be accessible, you need to bring them in scope:

```
struct Child : public Parent<CONFIG>
{
    using Base = Parent<Config>;
    using typename Base::Type;
    void x(Type p){}     // Compiler error. Cannot see Parent::Type
};
```

Comment: Is there any way to bring them all in to scope with one line, similar to a `using namespace std` rather than one `using` per type?

Comment: @user997112 Nope, not this way. You can only do that for non-template base classes.

Comment: @user997112 What we usually do is, we define a `Traits` class in the base class, `using Traits = Base::Traits;` and use types from that. Still you'll need constructs like `void x(typename Traits::Type)`.

Comment: There’s no ADL here, just ordinary unqualified lookup that never considers dependent base classes.

Comment: It's quite frustrating because I have many `Child` classes, each using the same type names (not types, just the type names) and it would have been great if `Parent` could have set them, to be accessed by `Child`.